# Excel 2010: Enter apostrophe in formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a condition in my excel cell, it enters `'123` into my cell for a condition. What I want to achieve is that excel understands this as a number formatted as text, but it doesn't, it just displays `'123`.

Normally, when entering '123 + enter, it does what it should. What is wrong in my case?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a formula that, if true, will try to return "'123"?

Answer (score 0):

Use `=text("123","@")`

Wrapping the number `123` inside of the `text` formula allows you to reformat it, and the `@` symbol tells excel to use it as text.